# C - strange fork() + execl() behaviour

Tags: c, unix, fork, exec, dup2

I'll try to be as specific as possible with my issue. My objective is to implement two sockets (client/server); the client has to send to the server an awk command + some lines of input. The server has to execute the awk command with the given input and send back to the client every line of awk's stdout and every line of awk's stderr, concatenated with the string "ERRLINEi" (i = line number).

I asked how to do this as I was completely lost and I got good advice to use fork, execl, pipes and dup2. So I tried to write this down:

```
void run_awk(char *command, char *out, char *err){
    int in_pipe[2]; //send input string from parent to child --> input
    int out_pipe[2]; //receive awk's stdout from child --> send back to client
    int err_pipe[2]; //receive awk's stderr from child --> write on fd 4, send back to client with errline
    pid_t p;
    if((pipe(in_pipe)+pipe(out_pipe)+pipe(err_pipe)) < 0) syscallerror("pipe");
    if((p = fork()) < 0) syscallerror("fork");
    if(p > 0){
        close(in_pipe[0]);  // Close reading end of first pipe
        close(out_pipe[1]); // Close writing end of second pipe
        write(in_pipe[1], command, strlen(command)+1);
        printf("parent process %d: sent input %s\n", getpid(), command);
        close(in_pipe[1]);
        // Wait for child to send out and err
        wait(NULL);
        char s_out[301];
        char s_err[301];
        int n = read(out_pipe[0], s_out, 300);
        int k = read(err_pipe[0], s_err, 300);
        if(n > 0) printf("parent %d: received output %s\n", getpid(), s_out);
        if(k > 0) printf("parent %d: received error %s\n", getpid(), s_err);
        close(out_pipe[0]);
        close(err_pipe[0]);
        close(err_pipe[1]);
    }
    else if(p == 0){
        close(in_pipe[1]);  // Close writing end of first pipe
        // Read a string using first pipe
        char buf[300];
        read(in_pipe[0], buf, 300);
        printf("child %d: received input %s\n", getpid(), buf);
        // Close all reading ends
        close(in_pipe[0]);
        close(out_pipe[0]);
        close(err_pipe[0]);
        dup2(out_pipe[1], 1); //set out_pipe[1] as stdout
        dup2(err_pipe[1], 2); //set err_pipe[1] as stderr
        close(err_pipe[1]);
        close(out_pipe[1]);
        execl("usr/bin/awk", "awk", buf, (char *)0); //at this point awk's
        exit(0);               //out and err should be redirected to the pipes
    }
}
```

But this isn't working. Note that this function is called in a while loop that loops until new input lines are received from the client. I wasn't really understanding why so I put a printf instruction before the function call (in the main function where run_awk() is invoked) and the result was that run_awk() was being called multiple times from the same process with the same input.

Note: my *out and *err parameters should be used for storing awk's results. I left them unused since I just wanted to see what was my program doing.

**UPDATE**
I understood some of the errors in my code. I took the forking part back to the main function, but I still have problems. Practically, what I need to do is: send one command (with senseful awk syntax) from parent to child (and I achieved this) and then making the child read the input lines (random text) one by one, from stdin, allowing execl to run like this:

```
execl("/usr/bin/awk", "awk", command, (char *)0)
```

My new code is:

```
if((t_fd = accept(l_fd, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL)) < 0) sockerror(2, 0); //accept connection from client
    recv(t_fd, &com_len, sizeof(int), 0); //receive command length
    command = malloc(com_len+1);
    rbytes = recv(t_fd, command, com_len, 0); //receive command
    command[rbytes] = '\0';
    printf("Received command: %s\n", command);
    if((pipe(in_pipe)+pipe(out_pipe)+pipe(err_pipe)) < 0) syscallerror("pipe"); //init pipes
    bool check = true;
    while(recv(t_fd, &inp_len, sizeof(int), 0) > 0){ //receive single input line length - loop while there are lines to read
        memset(input, 0, inp_len+1);
        recv(t_fd, input, inp_len, 0);  //receive input line
        if((p = fork()) < 0) syscallerror("fork");
        if(p > 0){
            close(in_pipe[0]);  // Close reading end of first pipe
            if(check){ //this makes the server write the command in the pipe just once
                write(in_pipe[1], command, strlen(command));
                check = false;
            }
            write(in_pipe[1], input, strlen(input)); //write the input line

            //close(in_pipe[1]); //I can't close it because other lines will be sent in the loop
            close(out_pipe[1]);
            close(err_pipe[1]);
            int n = read(out_pipe[0], out, 300); //read should block until child has produced output (you can assume it will always produce it)
            int k = read(err_pipe[0], err, 300);
            if(n > 0) printf("parent %d: received output %s\n", getpid(), out);
            if(k > 0) printf("parent %d: received error %s\n", getpid(), err);
            close(out_pipe[0]);
            close(err_pipe[0]);
            memset(out, 0, 301);
            memset(err, 0, 301);
        }
        else{
            close(in_pipe[1]);  // Close writing end of first pipe
            char com[300]; // Read command using first pipe
            read(in_pipe[0], com, 300);
            // Close all reading ends
            close(out_pipe[0]);
            close(err_pipe[0]);
            dup2(in_pipe[0], 0); //set correct file descriptors
            dup2(out_pipe[1], 1);
            dup2(err_pipe[1], 2);
            close(in_pipe[0]);
            close(err_pipe[1]);
            close(out_pipe[1]);
            if(execl("/usr/bin/awk", "awk", com, (char *)0) < 0) syscallerror("execl");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    close(in_pipe[1]);
    kill(p, SIGKILL);
```

If you see any uninitialized variables, it's because they are declared out of this loop. How can I solve this?

Comment: The question says you want to create sockets, the code creates pipes.

Comment: The sockets are the final objective. I have already implemented correct socket communication. My problem is to make the server socket execute the awk command.

Comment: `"usr/bin/awk"` should be `"/usr/bin/awk"` unless your current directory is the root directory.

Comment: The [`execl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execlp.3.html) function sets `errno` appropriately if it fails. You might want to check that.

Comment: Parent doesn't close `err_pipe[1]` before reading; it means that the read won't come up with EOF because the write end of the pipe is still open in some process.  You shouldn't exit with status 0 if the `execl` fails; and you should report the error returned if `execl()` returns.  You don't need to test that; it doesn't return unless it fails.  But you should report the error and exit with a non-zero status.

Comment: According to your problem description, the client (== parent) sends an `awk` program *and some `awk` input*.  Where's the input?  The child appears to be leaving its standard input alone, so it will use, and pass on to `awk`, the standard input stream it inherits from its parent.  Is there in fact any input coming through on that?  Is that ever *closed*, so that `awk` knows it has processed its whole input and can exit?

Comment: @Barmar you're right, thanks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger He says this is part of a larger socket-based server, I suspect the plan is to connect awk's `stdin` to the socket.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right too, I just changed that, awk is now running and throwing errors at me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger wrong. The parent process is not the client. I have only written a part of the server socket's code because writing all of my client and server would have been unnecessary. By the way, the parent writes the command (full awk program + input) string (which the child has no access to) to in_pipe[1], and the child reads it from in_pipe[0]. Is that wrong?

Comment: That may well be, @Barmar, but such an arrangement begs the question even more.  Could the problem be with the input?  Especially, could it arise from `awk` never seeing the end of the input, as a result of the output side of the client's socket remaining open?

Comment: That's definitely possible. The problem could be due to buffering of `awk` output.

Comment: Updated my code, it should be clearer now what I'm trying to do.